# Select specific fields from Model Instance in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3. In my application i need to get selected fields from Model instance. And the code looks like

```
searches.collect {|s| s.emp_search.find( :select => "id, name")}
```

From this code i am getting error message because of find  method is used in Model Instance. Now i wants to get id and name from the emp_search instance. Please guide me how to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 0):

If your result is intended to be something like

```
[
  [1, 'Search 1'],
  [2, 'Search 2'],
  [3, 'Search 3']
]
```

then you could go along the lines of

```
searches.map do |search| 
  search.emp_search.select([:id, :name]).map {|s| [s.id, s.name]}
end
```